# NX9/UG Knowledge Fusion script to add values to expressions

Tags: expression, siemens-nx

I'm new to Knowledge Fusion, I'm trying to create a .dfa script that will add some values from a surface or solid to expressions, so I can then export to excel.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DefClass: centers (%nx_application %ui_comp);

(Boolean) %on_solid?:           false;                          
(String Parameter) %ask_name:   "Centers";          
(string) %icon_name:            "section_inertia";              
(Integer) %edit_dialog:         ug_invokeClassDialog(self:);    
(List Uncached)                 %onObjectHighlight:             centers:;
(Boolean) %atTimeStamp?:        false;

(child) UI_Select:  {
        class,      %ui_comp_selection;
        Many,       False;
        Label,      "Select surface or solid to analyse";
        Tooltip,    "Select the Surface or Solid to analyse";
        FilterTriple,   {{ 70, 0, 35 },{ 70, 0, 36 }};   
}; 

(Instance) objet: ug_adoptObject(nth(1,UI_Select:SelectedObjects:));
```

This part finds the centers and add it to expressions:

```
(child uncached) x:         {
        Class,      ug_expression;
        Name,       "x";    
        Value,      localX(objet:centroid:);
};
(child uncached) y:         {
        Class,      ug_expression;
        Name,       "y";    
        Value,      localY(objet:centroid:);
};
(child uncached) z:         {
        Class,      ug_expression;
        Name,       "z";    
        Value,      localZ(objet:centroid:);
};
```

Now I'm trying to add surface area if the object selected is a surface, or volume is it is a solid body.

this is what I tried:

```
(child uncached) area:          {
        Class,      ug_expression;
        Name,       "area"; 
        Value,      area(objet:surface_area:);
};
```

this didn't work, the application crashes, saying the is no class surface_area.

I also have no idea how to make an if statement in the language.

It has been super hard to create this, there is almost no info online and I couldn't find documentation on functions etc, everything so far as been trial and error.

would very much appreciate some help and guidance on this
Thank so much

Answer (score 0):

I find out to find areas and volumes if anyone has the same problem.
Still could figure out how to do the if statement because I can't find a why to ask if object is a solid or surface.

However both work if both solids and surface, just give 0 for the volume of a surface obviously.

here is the code:

```
(child uncached) area:          {
    Class,          ug_expression;
    Name,           "area";
    Value,          object:Surface_Area:;
};
(child uncached) Volume:        {
    Class,          ug_expression;
    Name,           "Volume";
    Value,          object:Volume:;
};
```

How it help anyone trying to create custom NX functions